# Two tables with no unique values that I need to match and return value based on date range and zipcode fields

Tags: excel-formula, array-formulas

[image]

I have two sets of data; the first (Wind Claims) contains a StartDate, EndDate, and Zip Code field. The second (PLRB Wind) contains a Date, Zip Code, and Wind Speed field.

My goal is to get the Wind Speed from the PLRB Wind tab to the Wind Claims tab if the Date from the PLRB Wind tab is between the StartDate and EndDate on the wind Claims tab AND the Zip Code from the PLRB Wind tab matches the Zip Code on the Wind Claims tab. The point is to identify the wind speed where damage was reported.

I have tried a couple formulas; this one I actually got results but only 1227 out of 16822. I wouldnt expect to have a 100% match but definitely much more than what I am getting. I think the reason is because this formula is looking for the specific date and not looking at the date range:

```
=XLOOKUP(Z2&N2,'PLRB Wind'!$I$2:$I$78525&'PLRB Wind'!$D$2:$D$78525,'PLRB Wind'!$M$2:$M$78525,"")
```

I also tried an Index Match (this is just the Match piece of the formula)

```
=MATCH(1,IF('PLRB Wind'!D2>=$B$2:$B$16823,IF('PLRB Wind'!D2<='Wind Claims'!$C$2:$C$16823,IF('PLRB Wind'!I2='Wind Claims'!$Z$2:$Z$16823,1))),0)
```

Thank you in advance for looking at this. I appreciate any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a mock up of the data and expected output.  It makes it easier for use to visualize what you want.

Comment: Can you explain with some sample data and expected result? Wouldn't a minimum (`MINIFS`) and a maximum (`MAXIFS`) and or average windspeed (`AVERAGEIFS`) be more helpful? Using MATCH for instance would return the first found value, which may give a wrong impression.

Comment: I tried the MAXIFS like this: =MAXIFS('PLRB Wind'!$M:$M,'PLRB Wind'!$D:$D,">="&'Wind Claims'!$B:$B,'PLRB Wind'!$D:$D,"<="&$C:$C,'PLRB Wind'!$I:$I,'Wind Claims'!$Z:$Z)
All the results are 0.

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong if I don't know what's what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use power query for this. Do you know what power queries are?  I was upset when I found out because of all the useful ways I could have been using it before.

You might feel differently, though. Create a new copy of your workbook for this just in case you hate it. :-)

In the "Data" ribbon of Excel, in the Get & Transform section, there's a "From Table" button. Highlight your PLRB table (including the column titles) and click that "From Table" button to create a new query from it. It will create the table and the query.

A power query editor window will pop up, presenting your query as two steps, listed in the middle of the right sidebar. The first step is to get the information from your worksheet. The second step changes the data types. Click the icon to the left of each date column's title to change the type from datetime to date because why not. On the right sidebar, change the query name to `PLRB`.

Now click "Close & Load" on the home ribbon. It will create a new tab with the results of your table. Leave it for now. You can delete that tab later and it won't delete the query.

So, back to your worksheet, highlight the column-title row and data rows for first three columns of the wind claims table. Create another query from table. Call it `WindClaimsInput`. Again, correct the datetime columns to date columns

OKAY, so now you have two queries. They both read from your workbook but they could have been from another file or text file, etc. If you like this solution then your final form might be a worksheet that doesn't actually have any source data in it, just queries that gets the raw data from elsewhere and a tab that presents the third query we're about to make.

Now for the fun part.

While still in the power query editor editing your `WindClaimsInput` query, near the left edge of the "Home" ribbon there's a button named "manage...". Click it, then click "Reference" to create a third query that starts with the old one. Remember, queries are only instructions. We aren't copying data until we run the queries.

Now, find the button to add a column. It should open a dialog box asking the column name and formula. Name it "PLRB" and use this formula: `Table.SelectRows(PLRB, (r) => (r[Date] >= [CATFromDt] and r[Date] <= [CATThruDt] and r[ZipCode] = [ClaimZip]))` Table.SelectRows is a power query function that takes two arguments:

1. The table (or query that returns a table), and,
2. A function to run on each record (aka row) of the table and return true/false. In this case, we created a function that takes one argument (r) and returns true or false.

So the above formula says "Give me a table of all rows in PLRB for the given ClaimZip zip code that also has a Date between CATFromDt and CATThruDt." Since it's a column formula, it runs once per row in. Wind Claims.

Now you have a table where the last column is another table! Specifically, the rows from PLRB that are relevant for that Wind claims row. You can single-click on any of those cells in that last column to see the subtable.

To right of the last column's title will be a little "expand" icon. Click it, choose to aggregate by max wind speed. (The right edge of the "wind speed" choice will let you change it to maximum, or average, or whatever you like.) Unclick "Use original column name as prefix". Click okay. Don't worry, you can delete this new step and try again if I didn't describe it well.

Hit "Close and Load" to see it in your workbook. If it looks right, great! Otherwise, feel free to go back and edit some more.

And now you're done! Unlike formulas it doesn't automatically refresh but when you want to refresh your output based on your input tables you can refresh that query or, in the "Data" ribbon you can click "refresh all".

In the data ribbon of Excel, in the "Get & Transform" section, there's a "Show Queries" button that toggles a sidebar that displays your queries you've made. You probably only want to keep loading your third query, so you can change the "Load to..." of the other two queries to "Connection Only".

Sorry I can't do screenshots right now.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for taking the time to write all of this out for me! Brilliant solution!

Comment: Relieved it works for you! BTW, most of what you can do in PowerQuery doesn't require typing formulas but, like macros, code is generated in the background you can tweak as needed, etc. If you get to that point I recommend [powerquery.io](https://www.powerquery.io) as a reference. Microsoft's own documentation site is more detailed but in most cases powerquery.io lets you jump to what you're looking for much faster.