# Relatively search all cells above active cell until reach table header instead of absolute cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to even ask about this; hopefully this explanation is clear enough.

Using a VBA recorded macro, with the relative selection on, I have a formula that uses the `countif($C$656:C656,[@Column1])` (which is actually the cell directly below the Table Header, Column1)

The problem I'm facing is the formula doesn't translate as the variable locations because I don't know how to use relative code to actually tell vba to search all the way up the Table column until you reach the cell directly below the header. It must be relative because the table is not always created on row 655 and has varying numbers of rows within the table itself so I can't tell VBA `R[1]C[1]:R[367]c[1]` for example.

Below is the formula entered in the cell itself (B656).

```
=IF(B655="Column2",[@Column1],
IF(COUNTIF($C655:C$656,[@Column1]),
(CONCATENATE(TEXT([@Date],"yyyy-m-d"),
"_",TEXT([@Date],"hhmm-s"),
"_R-"&COUNTIF($C655:C$656,[@Column1]),
IF([@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]]="","","_"&[@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]]))),
[@Column1]))
```

Below is the VBA translation using the relative button turned on:

```
'Enter formula in cell under header (INCLUDES REPEATED DATES FOR DIFFERENT SPREADS)
    Range("TblAccountTradeHistory[[#Headers],[Column2]]").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[-1]C=""Column2"",[@Column1]," & Chr(10) & "IF(COUNTIF(R[-1]C3:R656C[1],[@Column1])," & Chr(10) & "(CONCATENATE(TEXT([@Date],""yyyy-m-d"")," & Chr(10) & """_"",TEXT([@Date],""hhmm-s"")," & Chr(10) & """_R-""&COUNTIF(R[-1]C3:R656C[1],[@Column1])," & Chr(10) & "IF([@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]]="""","""",""_""&[@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]])))," & Chr(10) & "[@Column1]))"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^NOTE: THERE'S A SEARCH ALL CELLS ABOVE THIS ROW THROUGH THE HEADER, BUT ABOVE FORMULA SAYS "R[-1]C3:R656C" WILL THAT MESS UP FOR TRANSACTIONS THAT AREN'T THAT LOW?
```

Anyone have thoughts of how to make this work?

[image: Attached is a screenshot example of my data selection on cell B664.]

Comment: Could you share the desired formula for cell `B664` as if it wasn't in a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use cell references within tables and much of your problem goes away.

Assuming your table is named "Table1", try inserting a new column titled DataRowsAbove with a formula of `=ROW()-ROW(Tables[#Headers]-1`

Then insert another column titled Column1Repeated with a formula of `=IF([@DataRowsAbove]=0,0,COUNTIF(OFFSET(Table1[#Headers][Column1],1,0,[@DataRowsAbove],1),[@Column1])`

The offset is the secret sauce, here. It gives you a range of every Column1 value above the current line without any cell address references.

Then your Column2 formula can be

```
=IF(
 [@Column1Repeated]=0,
 [@Column1],
 CONCATENATE(
  TEXT([@Date],"yyyy-m-d"),
  "_",
  TEXT([@Date],"hhmm-s"),
  "_R-",
  [@Column1Repeated],
  IF(
   [@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]]="",
   "",
   "_"&[@[TRANSACTION FEE ID]]
  )
 )
)
```

If that works for you, then...

- If you don't care about those two extra columns showing, you're fine!
- If you can insert two new column before A:A, move those two new column into the new A and B columns, then hide those columns, then your worksheet looks the same as it did before except that it starts with column C.
- If you can't do either of these, then you have to replace mentions of `[@DataRowsAbove]` & `[@Column1Repeated]` with their formulas instead of those two new columns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Eventually I end up pasting values, so the new columns is no prob.  I'll give it a try later today. :)

Comment: Great! I learned this the hard way, and created a rule of thumb for myself: "If a change to a table column formula doesn't change the entire column at once (without me having to drag the new formula down the column) then I'm doing it wrong."

Comment: Also, if you are copying and pasting into another Excel file, then you should definitely look into PowerQuery (the "Get & Transform" part of the Data ribbon). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70071563/two-tables-with-no-unique-values-that-i-need-to-match-and-return-value-based-on/70074755#70074755